# Issue related to getting distinct records using join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have following columns in `tblProject` dataTable:

```
ID,
Title,
Estimator,
ConstructionCoordinator,
ConstructionManager,
EnteredBy,
AssignedTo,
ProjectCoordinator,
SalesLead
```

All the above column without first two are entry of UserId of `tblUser` Datatable as follows

```
UserId,
UserName
```

i want to get all records from `tblProject` in which all the columns(without First Two i.e ID and Title) contains  `UserId of tblUser`

i tried following query,

```
 select * from Project PRJ
 inner join UserProfile UP on UP.UserId = PRJ.Estimator or UP.UserId = PRJ.ConstructionCoordinator
                    or UP.UserId = PRJ.ConstructionManager or UP.UserId = PRJ.EnteredBy or UP.UserId = PRJ.AssignedTo
                    or UP.UserId = PRJ.ProjectCoordinator or UP.UserId = PRJ.SalesLead
```

but i am getting duplicate records, in Column `ID and Title` how to get distinct data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set based thinking, where `intersect` is analogous to logical `AND` and `union` is analogous to logical `OR`, led me to this:

```
select UserId from UserProfile
intersect
( select Estimator from Project
  union
  select ConstructionCoordinator from Project
  union
  select ConstructionManager from Project
  union
  select EnteredBy from Project
  union
  select AssignedTo from Project
  union
  select ProjectCoordinator from Project
  union
  select SalesLead from Project );
```

To return all columns, as per you SQL, you could:

```
select * from Project where UserId in 
( select Estimator from Project
  union
  select ConstructionCoordinator from Project
  union
  select ConstructionManager from Project
  union
  select EnteredBy from Project
  union
  select AssignedTo from Project
  union
  select ProjectCoordinator from Project
  union
  select SalesLead from Project );
```